# Using Regex to parse logs

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
CALL ID             : 6DC2H-9992EB26H-692DH-7996H-2986H-9BH-7996H-9C66H-ACH
CALL START          : 2929-98-26  22:56:96.62  
CALL PHASE : RELEASE
SIGNALLING COMPLETE : 2929-98-26  22:56:62.29  STAT STATE : IDLE
ANSWER              :                          CLEAR CODE : 9B29H
CHARGING END        :                          CLEAR INFO : AIF_SS 9992H 9A2CH
PAGING TIME         : 929                      CLEAR PART : SUB B
```

My goal is to convert the file to a csv file.

Here's my approach so far :

1. Read the text file by line and use Regex to get the names of the variables

```py
variables = []
with open(r'C:\Users\younes\Desktop\internship material\OBSFAILA.txt') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        line = f.readline()
        x = re.search("(^(.*?):)",line)
        if(x1):
            variables.append(x.group(0))
```

since i know there are 46 variables i just get the first 46 elements of the list

```py
var = variables[1:46]

var_names = []
for variable in var:
    new = re.sub(":","",variable)
    var_names.append(new)
```

2. Create a list for each variable

```py
for n in range(0, 100):
    globals()['strg%s' % n] = []

with open(r'C:\Users\younes\Desktop\internship material\OBSFAILA.txt') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        line = f.readline()
        for i in range (0,len(var)) :
            num = f'{i}'
            x = re.search("^"+var[i]+".*", line)
            if(x):
                exec('strg'+num+'.append(x.group(0))')
```

3. Compile all the lists into a DataFrame

```py
list = []
for i in range(0,len(var)):
    num = f'{i}'
    exec('list.append(strg'+num+')')

df = pd.DataFrame(list).transpose()
df.columns = var_names
```

This method works for the majority of the lines but it doesnt for the lines where there are more than one variable like this one, it doesn't take into account the second variable.

```
SIGNALLING COMPLETE : 2929-98-26  22:56:62.29  STAT STATE : IDLE
```

Is there a way to correct this problem ?

Comment: `/CALL START : (.*) CALL PHASE : (.*)/` would get you: `2929-98-26 22:56:96.62` and
`RELEASE`

Comment: Do you have any feedback for the answer from user696969 below, who took the time and trouble to try to help you with your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want just to separate the variables from the `middle` of the line you can try this:

```py
log = "CALL START : 2929-98-26 22:56:96.62 CALL PHASE : RELEASE"
items = log.split("CALL")[1:] # split by "CALL" and take from 1st elem to last
items = ["CALL" + item for item in items] # add again call
for item in items:
    print(item)
```

output

```sh
CALL START : 2929-98-26 22:56:96.62 
CALL PHASE : RELEASE
```

this is the fastest i came up with

**EDIT**

if you just want to extract the values of each variable you can try this:

```py
print()

variables = [":".join(item.split(":")[1:]).strip() for item in items]
for variable in variables:
    print(variable)
```

continuation of the above code.

output

```
2929-98-26 22:56:96.62
RELEASE
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `re.search` with pattern `r'CALL START : (.*) CALL PHASE : (.*)'` to get the value for `CALL START` and `CALL PHASE`, assuming you know the variable name to be `CALL START` and `CALL PHASE`

```
import re

line = "CALL START : 2929-98-26 22:56:96.62 CALL PHASE : RELEASE"

match = re.search(r'CALL START : (.*) CALL PHASE : (.*)', line)

if match:
   CALL_START = match.group(1)
   CALL_PHASE = match.group(2)
else:
   print "No match!!"
```

Comment: is there a way to this if i dont know the names of the variables ?